# How to throttle function call on mouse event with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm calling a function on the "mousemove" event of a DOM element, using D3.js 's `.on()`, like so :

```
d3.select("#myelement").on("mousemove", myfunc);
function myfunc(){
    // Just to show that I need to get the mouse coordinates here
    console.log(d3.mouse(this));
}
```

I need the function I'm calling to be aware of the event, i.e. the mouse coordinates.

Since the rest of my code is quite computationally expensive, I'd like to throttle the calls to `myfunc`, say every 200 ms.

How can I do that while preserving the value of `this` in `myfunc` (so that `d3.mouse(this)` still works) ? 
I've tried this debounce function : https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function 
And also this : https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls
But I'm unable to get those to work the way I want.

Comment: can you try d3.select("#myelement").mousemove(function(e){ console.log(e); })

Comment: @cbalakus There is no `mousemove` method in D3.

Comment: ".mousemove()" is not a function on a d3 selection, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: If you strictly want to limit the calls of your function, just count. Set a counter to 0 outside your function, then in the function increase the counter until it reaches a threshold, and then do your action and reset the counter to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Gerardo Furtado's answer, I managed to solve my problem by adapting the throttle function from [this page](https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls) like so :

```
function throttle(fn, threshhold, scope) {
  threshhold || (threshhold = 250);
  var last,
      deferTimer;
  return function () {
    var context = scope || this;

    var now = +new Date,
        args = arguments,
        event = d3.event;
    if (last && now < last + threshhold) {
      // hold on to it
      clearTimeout(deferTimer);
      deferTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        last = now;
          d3.event = event;
        fn.apply(context, args);
      }, threshhold);
    } else {
      last = now;
        d3.event = event;
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }
  };
}
});
```

Now the callback is aware of the d3.event and d3.mouse(this) can be used normally inside the function.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not passing `this` to the debounce function, which is quite easy, as you can see in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w37tw2ud/) (I'm linking a JSFiddle because the Stack snippet freezes when logging `this` or a D3 selection).

The real problem is passing the D3 event: since `d3.event` is null after the event has finished, you have to keep a reference to it. Otherwise, you'll have a `Cannot read property 'sourceEvent' of null` error when trying to use `d3.mouse()`.

So, using the function of your [second link](https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls), we can modify it to keep a reference to the D3 event:

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
    var timer = null;
    return function() {
        var context = this,
            args = arguments,
            evt = d3.event;
            //we get the D3 event here
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            d3.event = evt;
            //and use the reference here
            fn.apply(context, args);
        }, delay);
    };
}
```

Here is the demo, hover over the big circle, slowly moving your mouse:

```js
var circle = d3.select("circle");

circle.on("mousemove", debounce(function() {
  console.log(d3.mouse(this));
}, 250));

function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timer = null;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments,
      evt = d3.event;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
     d3.event = evt;
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 30% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle cx="120" cy="80" r="50" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```

PS: In both the JSFiddle and in the Stack snippet the function is called only when you **stop** moving the mouse, which is not the desired behaviour for a `mousemove`. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and in particular for point out that the problem is about the event, not this. Your example works fine I think for a debounce function. I'll try to do the same thing in the throttle function (see the second link) and I'll report here.

Comment: I've posted an answer using your idea inside a "real" throttle function. If you want to update your answer I'll mark yours as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, no worries. You can accept your own answer (in a couple of days)!

Comment: I like this idea, but it doesn't seem to work for me anymore with d3 v4. I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property event of #<Object> which has only a getter`.

Comment: @bgschiller my answer **already uses** D3 v4. Your issue is a different one, and the problem is not D3 version. If you have additional information, please feel free to write it as an answer, detailing what was your issue and why your proposed change worked.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado huh, there must be something I'm not understanding. When I try to set d3.event as in your code, the browser gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property event of #<Object> which has only a getter`. In node, it seems to fail silently: https://imgur.com/a/d3yln . I'm still fighting this problem though, so I'd love some guidance.

Comment: @bgschiller In that case I suggest that you post a *new question*, with all the relevand details: are you using Typescript? Node? Angular? React? Try to create a [MCVE], so we can check what's happening. But, as you can see in the snippet, my code works with D3 v4. Have in mind that my solution here works in the browser, not in a Node environment.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I am not sure if it would preserve the `this` keyword in your case though, you can give it try.

Instead of coding your own `throttle` or `debounce`, you could simply use a helper library like lodash and pass your function to the API to get a throttled version of your function:

Example with jQuery, but should also work with d3:

```
// Avoid excessively updating the position while scrolling.
jQuery(window).on('scroll', _.throttle(updatePosition, 100));
```

https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle

Comment: Suggesting a different library which is not among the OP's tags should be a comment, not an answer. But the main problem with your suggestion is this: it will not work. `d3.mouse` is set by D3 and then passed to the event handler; Because of that, only events registered by D3, with the `.on()` function, can use `d3.mouse`. It will simply not work if you use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You do **not** need a big segment of code or an oversized library like D3js for a decent throttle function. The purpose of a throttle function is to reduce browser resources, not to apply so much overhead that you are using even more. Also, my different uses for throttle functions require many different circumstances for them. Here is my list of things that a 'good' throttle function needs that this one has.

- Minimal overhead.
- Immediate function call if it has been more than *interval* MS since the last call.
- Avoiding executing function for another *interval* MS.
- Delaying excessive event firing instead of dropping the event altogether.
- Updates the delayed event when need be so that it doesn't become 'stale'.
- Prevents the default action of the event when the throttled function is delayed.
- Be able to remove the throttle event listener listener.

And, I believe that the following throttle function satisfies all of those.

```
var cachedThrottleFuncs = [],
    minimumInterval = 200; // minimum interval between throttled function calls
function throttle(func, obj, evt) {
    var timeouttype = 0,
        curFunc;
    function lowerTimeoutType(f){
        timeouttype=0;
        if (curFunc !== undefined){
            curFunc();
            curFunc = undefined;
        }
    };
    return cachedThrottleFuncs[ ~(
        ~cachedThrottleFuncs.indexOf(func) || 
        ~(
          cachedThrottleFuncs.push(function(Evt) {
            switch (timeouttype){
                case 0: // Execute immediatly
                    ++timeouttype;
                    func.call(Evt.target, Evt);
                    setTimeout(lowerTimeoutType, minimumInterval);
                    break;
                case 1: // Delayed execute
                    curFunc = func.bind(Evt.target, Evt);
                    Evt.preventDefault();
            }
          }) - 1
        )
    )];
};
function listen(obj, evt, func){
    obj.addEventListener(evt, throttle(func, obj, evt));
};
function mute(obj, evt, func){
    obj.removeEventListener(evt, throttle(func, obj, evt));
}
```

Example usage:

```
listen(document.body, 'scroll', function whenbodyscrolls(){
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 400)
        mute(document.body, 'scroll', whenbodyscrolls();
    else
        console.log('Body scrolled!')
});
```

Alternatively, if you only need to add event listeners, and you do not need to remove event listeners, then you can use the following even simpler version.

```
var minimumInterval = 200; // minimum interval between throttled function calls
function throttle(func, obj, evt) {
    var timeouttype = 0,
        curEvt = null;
    function lowerTimeoutType(f){
        timeouttype=0;
        if (curEvt !== null){
            func(curEvt);
            curEvt = null;
        }
    };
    return function(Evt) {
        switch (timeouttype){
            case 0: // Execute immediately
                ++timeouttype; // increase the timeouttype
                func(Evt);
                // Now, make it so that the timeouttype resets later
                setTimeout(lowerTimeoutType, minimumInterval);
                break;
            case 1: // Delayed execute
                // make it so that when timeouttype expires, your function
                // is called with the freshest event
                curEvt = Evt;
                Evt.preventDefault();
        }
    };
};
```

By default, this throttles the function to at most one call every 200ms. To change the interval to a different number of milliseconds, then simply change the value of `minimumInterval`.